# Android application installation tracking by AdMob click

Tags: android, admob

I got an android app that show adds on different screens of this app. What I want to do is, I want to show the list of Android apps installed through my application AdMob click. 
Please suggest a way to do so.
I'm using Interstitial Ads.

Comment: I believe you are using banner ads

Comment: Using  Interstitial too

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way track the app install through admob ads.Specially, it is not possible if you want to track installs from banner and interstitial ads.

Though you can use this hack for native advanced ads.As native advanced ads gives you each parameter of the ad - headline, subtitle, app icon etc.
On the click event of the ad (which would redirect to the playstore in case of AppInstallAds) you can save the headline which will tell you the app name and you can track it at your own level.

```
public static void populateAppInstallAdView(NativeAppInstallAd nativeAppInstallAd, NativeAppInstallAdView adView) {
    adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_headline));
    adView.setImageView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_image));
    adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_body));
    adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_call_to_action));
    adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_app_icon));
    adView.setPriceView(adView.findViewById(R.id.appinstall_price));

    // Assign native ad object to the native view.
    adView.setNativeAd(nativeAppInstallAd);
}
```

Headline set here will provide the app name.